# How do i target or focus drop-down li which is active when a input is focused

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**JQUERY**

```
$(".share-drop .dropdown-notif").keydown(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parents('.share').find('.share-drop .dropdown-notif').show();
        if ($(this).val() == '') {
            $('.share-drop .dropdown-notif').hide();
        }
        if (e.which == 40) {
            var next = $('.selected').removeClass('selected').next('li');
            next = next.length > 0 ? next : $('.focus li:eq(0)');
            next.addClass('selected').children('a').focus();
        } else if (e.which == 38) {
            var prev = $('.selected').removeClass('selected').prev('li');
            prev = prev.length > 0 ? prev : $('.focus li').last();
            prev.addClass('selected').children('a').focus();
        }
    });
```

I have a drop-down option which will trigger on a keyup function of input text. I need to select those options using my up and down arrow keys I have been trying this using keydown where i couldn't able to move further. Can anyone help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Here is the [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/c9U3s/1/)

Comment: If possible, try to narrow down the code you put in the question to the absolute minimum needed with any relevance to the question. Leave the rest for the fiddle.

Comment: Try to make it work and then use [http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/)

Comment: I don't need any plugin for this will u able suggest any changes to my code

Answer (score 1):

I made a couple of changes to your fiddle and it started working for the up and down key after you do some typing; eg type 'te' then press up and down:

http://jsfiddle.net/c9U3s/2/

The keydown event binding needs to be on the input element itself, and you need to allow preventDefault:

```
$(".input-hold input").keydown(function (e) {
        //e.preventDefault();
```

and you need an initial selected class somewhere, for your logic to then sucessfully kick in, so I added this to the HTML:

```
<li class="selected"><a>testmail@test.com</a>
```

I think there's a couple more bug to step through, (eg what happens when you reach the end of the list with the down key?), but this will hopefully get you started.

This shows you how you can control the scrollTop of the dropdown, so you can scroll to view selected elements:

http://jsfiddle.net/c9U3s/3/

but again, some work needed to refine it to be truly nice.

Comment: My ul is not scrolling to the selected li to get into focus when it reaches the max height.

Comment: Can u able to get me a alternate suggestion or code for me

Comment: I see - I just added a quick oneliner to show you how you can scroll the dropdown. You'll need to do some work to make it more intuitive for the user, I think.

Comment: how to make it loop any suggestions and the altered code works only for the first time

Comment: Yep, you have a fair few bugs to work through in this code. Regarding looping, your logic is OK, but you need to think about how you select the first element in the case next.length == 0. Regarding only working the first time, hopefully I have shown you how to fix some of the things that were holding you back, and you can rework your code to get this to work exactly how you want. Good luck!